# as.POSIXct convert into wrong format

Tags: r, posixct

Does anyone know why `POSIXct` does not recognize my dates and correctly converts them?

```
> head(as.character(mCRC$inkldato))
[1] "25/09/14" "03/10/14" "08/10/14" "14/10/14" "10/12/14" "03/11/14"
```

out

```
 > head(as.POSIXct(as.character(mCRC$inkldato),format="%d/%m/%Y"))
 [1] "0014-09-25 LMT" "0014-10-03 LMT" "0014-10-08 LMT" "0014-10-14 LMT" "0014-12-10 LMT" "0014-11-03 LMT"
```

Comment: thanks. worked. Why is that?

Comment: %Y: 4-digit year (1982)
%y: 2-digit year (82)

Answer (score 3):

The two-digit year format is `%y` and `%Y` is for 4 digit year

```
as.POSIXct(v1,format="%d/%m/%y")
#[1] "2014-09-25 IST" "2014-10-03 IST" "2014-10-08 IST" 
#[4] "2014-10-14 IST" "2014-12-10 IST" "2014-11-03 IST"
```

---

This can be easily done with `lubridate` which doesn't have a problem with 4 digit or 2 digit year as long as we specify the order of day-month-year correctly

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(v1)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("25/09/14", "03/10/14", "08/10/14", "14/10/14", "10/12/14", "03/11/14")
```